# How do I return an iterator over a 2D array with the enumeration indices included?

Tags: iterator, rust

I have a struct containing a 2D array:

```
struct Block;

struct World {
    blocks: [[Block; 10]; 10],
}
```

How could I write a function which returns an iterator over a 2D array, but with the enumeration indices included?

```
fn enumerate_blocks(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &Block)>
```

I managed to write an implementation of the function which just returns an iterator without enumeration indices:

```
fn blocks(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &Block> {
    self.blocks.iter().flat_map(|x| x.iter())
}
```

If I call [`Iterator::enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) once, I will get an iterator over `(usize, [B; 10])`s. What I can do next to get an iterator over `(usize, usize, B)`s?

I know I could make the function return a custom struct then implement `Iterator`, like `image` does, but ideally I would like to avoid this.

Comment: This appears fairly low effort... [searching the Rust docs for enumerate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html?search=enumerate) points to [`Iterator::enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) which seems to be about 95% of what you are asking. Assuming you did that research, what problems did you have when trying to use it?

Comment: The problem is I want to enumerate over a 2D array `[[B; 10]; 10]`. Or rather, return an iterator which can iterate over a 2D array. If I call enumerate once, I will get an iterator over `(usize, [B; 10])`s. My question is what I can do next to get an iterator over `(usize, usize, B)`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I call `Iterator::enumerate` once, I will get an iterator over `(usize, [B; 10])`s. What I can do next to get an iterator over `(usize, usize, B)`s?

Call [`Iterator::enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) on the inner array in the same way, continuing to use [`Iterator::flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) to combine them. Use [`Iterator::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) to add the outer index to the inner tuple.

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Block;

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct World {
    blocks: [[Block; 2]; 3],
}

impl World {
    fn blocks(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &Block)> {
        self.blocks
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .flat_map(|(x, v)| v.iter().enumerate().map(move |(y, v)| (x, y, v)))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let w = World::default();
    for (x, y, v) in w.blocks() {
        println!("{}, {}, {:?}", x, y, v)
    }
}
```

```
0, 0, Block
0, 1, Block
1, 0, Block
1, 1, Block
2, 0, Block
2, 1, Block
```

Comment: Great, thank you. This works perfectly for me. Could you possibly explain why `move` is needed?

Comment: @JamesHinshelwood without it, the compiler assumes you want to place a reference to `x` in the tuple, instead of copying the value.